# I have a validate function in React/Reactstrap which I'm applying to multiple fields, however all fields are validating at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

Here's my code so far (just the relevant parts, and I'm also using availity-reactstrap-validation just FYI):

```
export default class CustomModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            toolPlatform: [],
            workstream: [],
            opsarea: [],
            campus: [],
            riskcat: [],
            activeItem: this.props.activeItem,
        validate: {
            textState: '',
        },
        };
    }

validateText(e) {
        const textRex = /^(?!\s*$).+/;
        const { validate } = this.state
            if (textRex.test(e.target.value)) {
                validate.textState = 'has-success'
            } else {
                validate.textState = 'has-danger'
            }
            this.setState( {validate})
        };


render() {
        const { toggle, onSave } = this.props;
        return (            
            <Modal isOpen={true} toggle={toggle}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}> Tool Details </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <AvForm onValidSubmit = {() => onSave(this.state.activeItem)}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="title">Title</Label>
                            <AvInput valid 
                                type="text"
                                name="title"
                                value={this.state.activeItem.title}
                                //onChange={this.handleChange}
                                placeholder="Tool Name"
                                valid={ this.state.validate.textState === 'has-success' }
                                invalid={ this.state.validate.textState === 'has-danger' }
                                onChange={ (e) => {
                                    this.validateText(e)
                                    this.handleChange(e)
                                }}
                                required
                            />
                        </FormGroup> 
                        <AvGroup>
                            <Label for="description">Description</Label>
                            <AvInput valid
                                type="text"
                                name="description"
                                value={this.state.activeItem.description}
                                valid={ this.state.validate.textState === 'has-success' }
                                invalid={ this.state.validate.textState === 'has-danger' }
                                placeholder="Tool description"
                                onChange={ (e) => {
                                    this.validateText(e)
                                    this.handleChange(e)
                                }}
                                required
                            />
```

The validation works, however when I start typing in one of the fields, both fields are validated at the same time. This makes sense, and I get why it's doing it, but I'm not 100% sure how to change the syntax to only validate the fields I'm typing in.

Hope that makes sense!  I'm sure it's fairly basic to change, I'm just new, and learning, so I can't quite get the right syntax.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both of your input fields are referencing the same validation state value `this.state.validate.textState`

Comment: You need to store the value and validity of each field independently in state, rather than one state value for all of them

Comment: @Jackson Yep I figured that's the issue, I'm just not sure how to fix it :D

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444, are you able to help me out with the syntax? I've been googling furiously, but it's hard to hit the right search terms, and as I'm still learning I don't have a good grasp on the options available

Comment: @simonk83 essentially `this.state.validate` would have a property per input field, and when you validate you pass in that property, e.g. `this.validateText(e, "title")` and update THAT property accordingly, i.e. `this.setState( {validate: {...validate, [field]:"has-success"}})` or something. Also another note, you're directly mutating the state in your `validateText` function, since destructuring doens't create a new object, just a reference to the state object, which you then directly update. Make sure not to mutate state in React, make copies of things

Comment: Hmm. Ok I get what you mean, and it makes sense, but I'm not much closer to actually making it work haha (not you're fault, I'm just too new to understand how to implement it I guess). Back to google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need two different fields for your textState, otherwise they share the same:

```
this.state = {
        data: [],
        toolPlatform: [],
        workstream: [],
        opsarea: [],
        campus: [],
        riskcat: [],
        activeItem: this.props.activeItem,
        validate: {
            textState: {
                title: '',
                description: '',
            },
        },
    };
```

Then check e.target.name to determine which field of textState to update (you could also pass it as an argument in this function)

```
validateText ( e ) {
    const textRex = /^(?!\s*$).+/; 

    // If test is true / false
    const fieldTextState = textRex.test( e.target.value ) ? 'has-success' : 'has-danger'

    // Create textState object with all the fields
    const textState = Object.assign( {}, this.state.validate.textState, { [ e.target.name ]: fieldTextState})

    this.setState( { validate : { textState  } } )
};
```

Also, set specific valid and invalid for each input

```
                         <AvInput valid
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            value={ this.state.activeItem.title }
                            //onChange={this.handleChange}
                            placeholder="Tool Name"
                            valid={ this.state.validate.textState.title === 'has-success' }
                            invalid={ this.state.validate.textState.title === 'has-danger' }
                            onChange={ ( e ) => {
                                this.validateText( e )
                                this.handleChange( e )
                            } }
                            required
                        />
```

and

```
                        <AvInput valid
                            type="text"
                            name="description"
                            value={ this.state.activeItem.description }
                            valid={ this.state.validate.textState.description === 'has-success' }
                            invalid={ this.state.validate.textState.description === 'has-danger' }
                            placeholder="Tool description"
                            onChange={ ( e ) => {
                                this.validateText( e )
                                this.handleChange( e )
                            } }
                            required
                        />
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that. The good news is, the invalid results now work independently (as in if one fails, it doesn't mark the other as failed). The bad news is, the valid result doesn't seem to apply at all (it doesn't get the nice green outline and tick mark as it did previously). I'll do my best to debug it but that might take me the rest of the day :D

Comment: Ok I think it's because you're assigning fieldTextState (so the result of the regex) to e.name, which isn't defined anywhere. So in the Variables window I see:
textstate:
description: ""
title: ""
undefined: "has-success"

Comment: Got it (I think!). I added `const { name} = e.target;` to the validateText function, and changed `[e.name] to [name]`.


Thanks so much for that though, I've been trying to get this working literally all day :D

Comment: And turns out I can just do  `[e.target.name]` and not worry about the const. That's done the trick, thanks again!

Comment: Do `validateText` and `handleChange` need to protect themselves from a null `e`? I guess for `onChange` it would matter what triggers it.